# GCC warns of out-of-bounds access only in a static_cast

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings, access-violation

GCC warns of *out-of-bounds array access* only when used in a `static_cast` even with most of the warning options enabled.

The sample code ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/Ge41915fj)):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <print>

int main()
{
    int arr[ 5 ] { };
    std::iota( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), 1 );

    //                                  <no warning>                          -<warning>-----
    std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", *(arr - 1), static_cast<const void*>(&( *(arr - 1) )) );
    //                                  <no warning>                         -<warning>-
    std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", arr[ -1 ], static_cast<const void*>(&arr[ -1 ]) );

    int* const ptr { arr + 2 };
    //                                  <no warning>                         -<warning>-
    std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", ptr[ -3 ], static_cast<const void*>(&ptr[ -3 ]) );
}
```

The compiler output:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:12:54: warning: array subscript -1 is outside array bounds of 'int [5]' [-Warray-bounds=]
   12 |     std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", *(arr - 1), static_cast<const void*>(&( *(arr - 1) )) );
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:9: note: at offset -4 into object 'arr' of size 20
    8 |     int arr[ 5 ] { };
      |         ^~~
<source>:14:78: warning: array subscript -1 is below array bounds of 'int [5]' [-Warray-bounds=]
   14 |     std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", arr[ -1 ], static_cast<const void*>(&arr[ -1 ]) );
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:9: note: while referencing 'arr'
    8 |     int arr[ 5 ] { };
      |         ^~~
<source>:18:53: warning: array subscript -1 is outside array bounds of 'int [5]' [-Warray-bounds=]
   18 |     std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", ptr[ -3 ], static_cast<const void*>(&ptr[ -3 ]) );
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:9: note: at offset -4 into object 'arr' of size 20
    8 |     int arr[ 5 ] { };
      |         ^~~
```

For instance, I naturally expect to see a warning for `*(arr - 1)` too. But apparently, only the expressions in the `static_cast`s (e.g. `&( *(arr - 1) )`) are pedantically checked for the presence of invalid accesses.

Is this a bug in GCC? Because the code is pretty trivial and explicit. I expect a compiler to display warnings at least in such simple scenarios.

Note: Clang is even worse and only warns about `arr[ -1 ]`.

Comment: The check for this warning is done relatively late and is affected by optimization of the surrounding code. So it will be specific to where exactly the expression appears. For example if you call an opaque function instead, then GCC complains on all indirections (https://godbolt.org/z/Tv14sWcdE). If you define the function however so that it can be inlined to a noop, then GCC won't warn on any (https://godbolt.org/z/jTPx7q8bo). I do not think they guarantee some consistent static analysis of the source code. That's what static analysers are for.

Comment: @user17732522 That's kind of messy. Even with the warning options on, one could expect a bit of help from the compiler. As you mentioned, a static analyzer is probably a must for correcting any C++ code to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

These warnings you will only occur when optimisation is enabled.  The *abstract interpretation* that occurs in the optimiser allow it to detect *some **potential*** runtime errors at compile time.  They are opportunistic warnings enabled by the way the optimiser works - you cannot expect the same results across all compilers, or even at different optimisation settings.

In this case you are passing the expressions as *variadic arguments* so although you have cast to a const pointer, `println()` makes no promises to respect that - the variadic arguments have no specific type defined compile time.  So the compiler sees that you are passing a *const pointer* with no idea how the receiving function is going to use it, so there is a *potential* for an out of bounds *write access*.

It is not the `static_cast` that causes this, it is the *taking of address* `&`.  The cast is necessary to comply with the format specifier.  I suspect if the compiler were not format specifier aware  (which it need not be), you would get the warning without the cast.

In the case of the expression `*(arr-1)` that is a read access and pass by value (not a pointer) and although you may not get a useful result, you are not modifying the out-of-bounds location, so there is noting to warn about.

You can simplify the test to demonstrate the behaviour is nothing to do with the static cast and everything to do with *writing* or *potentially* writing out-of-bounds using the following expressions:

```
int x = *(arr-1) ;      // No warning - out of bounds read
*(arr-1) = 0 ;          // warning: array subscript 4611686018427387903 is above array bounds of 'int [5]'
int* p = &(*(arr-1)) ;  // no warning, juts taken the address, not written to.
*p = 2 ;                // warning: array subscript -1 is outside array bounds of 'int [5]'
```

Comment: Interesting. But I suppose a read violation is also UB. Shouldn't the compiler warn in all cases?

Comment: "_In this case you are passing the expressions as variadic arguments_"/"the variadic arguments have no specific type defined compile time": No, `std::println` is a variadic template, not a variadic function. It knows the type.

Comment: "_It is not the static_cast that causes this, it is the taking of address &._": GCC also warns already if only an out-of-bounds pointer is formed (which is already UB), see https://godbolt.org/z/YbeYnn4qq. It doesn't warn only on dereference/access through that pointer.

Comment: @digito_evo perhaps, but as a systems level language, the ability to read arbitrary memory locations and do things "safer" languages will not allow is arguably required in many cases.  The behaviour, defined or not,  is likely to be that it reads the memory location before the first element, what is certainly _non-deterministic_ is what value it will have and what adjacent data object (if any) it belongs to. Again _arguably_ the error (and point of failure) is not in reading that value, but in what might be done with that value - any arithmetic or array index using that will also be undefined.

Comment: @user17732522  Good point re variadic template; I'll take your word for it without delving into the source for that.  It was just a hypothesis.  Re your godbolt my main point was that "_It is not the static_cast that causes this_", but it is an interesting result nonetheless, that if occurs without any potential for write.  I have no hypothesis for that.  Only that the optimiser catches some but not all, I guess it depends on the depth of its analysis - the warnings are a byproduct of optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that array indices are within the valid range would solve this

````cpp
int main()
{
    int arr[ 5 ] { };
    std::iota( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), 1 );

    // The valid indices for arr are 0 to 4. Negative indices are out of bounds.
    // We can't fix this by changing the index because we don't know what the intended behavior was.
    // So, we will comment out these lines.
    // std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", *(arr - 1), static_cast<const void*>(&( *(arr - 1) )) );
    // std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", arr[ -1 ], static_cast<const void*>(&arr[ -1 ]) );

    int* const ptr { arr + 2 };

    // The valid indices for ptr are -2 to 2 because ptr points to the middle of arr.
    // -3 is out of bounds. We can't fix this by changing the index because we don't know what the intended behavior was.
    // So, we will comment out this line.
    // std::println( "{} at address: {:p}", ptr[ -3 ], static_cast<const void*>(&ptr[ -3 ]) );
}```
````